# Total Space of Classifying Space Contractible

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles, classifying-spaces

I have a question about the topological intuition that the total space $EG$ of the classifying space $BG$ is ***contractible***.

Danny Calegari's "NOTES ON FIBER BUNDLES" on page 4 there is suggested following consideration:

[image]

For a group $G$ the total space $EG$ is homotopy equivalent to the [***join***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(topology)) $G*G*...*G$.

I don't understand why this "argument" justifies the contractibility of $EG$.

For example if we take $G:=\{e, a\} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$ then the join $G*G$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$ which is hot contractible.

[image]

Where is the error in my reasonings? Is there an intuitive approach to understand/imagine why this space $EG \sim G*G*...*G$ is contractible?

(...I know there is still a long way for me to become a Picasso...)

Comment: I have noticed you are going through a lot of material: étale cohomology, intersection theory, and now algebraic topology. I wish you all the best!

Comment: Thank you. While reading some papers and encountering some cross references one becomes astonished how little one really knows :)

Comment: Hint: First prove that every finite subcomplex $C\subset G*...*G$ contracts to a point in $(G*...*G)*G$ via a straight-line homotopy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim is that the *infinite* join $G*G*G*\dots$ is contractible, so your example with $G*G$ is irrelevant.  As the argument says, you can justify this using the fact that joins increase connectivity: if $X$ is $n$-connected and $Y$ is $m$-connected then $X*Y$ is $(n+m+1)$-connected.  (See the comments at [Connectedness of the join of two spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2998699/connectedness-of-the-join-of-two-spaces) for a sketch of one way to prove this fact.)  It follows by induction that the $n$-fold join $G*G*\dots*G$ is $(n-2)$-connected for all $n$ and so the infinite join is contractible.

Alternatively, here is an easier argument.  Note that if $X$ is any space and $Y$ is any nonempty space, then the inclusion $X\to X*Y$ is nullhomotopic (any point of $Y$ gives a cone over $X$ in $X*Y$).  The infinite join is just the colimit of the inclusions $G\to G*G\to G*G*G\to\dots$, and each of these inclusions is nullhomotopic, so the colimit is contractible.

For intuition, the example $G=\mathbb{Z}/2$ may be helpful.  In that case, $X*G$ is just the suspension of $X$, and so the $n$-fold join $G*G*\dots *G$ is just $S^{n-1}$, and in the limit you get the infinite sphere $S^\infty$ which is contractible.